# GitKraken push failed, privacy restriction

Tags: windows, git, github, restriction, gitkraken

i wanted to try GitKraken on Windows 10, but i keep getting this error

```
Push failed on refs/heads/master: push declined due to email privacy restriction
```

i do not want to change the privacy settings on GitHub, do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As [documented at on the GitHub blog](https://blog.github.com/2017-04-11-private-emails-now-more-private/), this occurs because you're trying to push commits that contain your real email address and you've configured GitHub to block pushes that do that.

First, run `git config --show-origin --get user.email` to find out where your email address is set.  If you don't see any output, it might be set in the `EMAIL` environment variable.  Change the configuration file or the environment variable to use the masked address that GitHub has provided for you.

Then, use `git log --format=fuller` to find the commits on your branch that have your real email address in them, and then find the commit *before* that one.  For example, it could be the commit starting with `abc1234`.

Then, run `git rebase -x 'git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author' abc1234` (substituting the real commit ID in place), and your commits will be rewritten to use the new email address.  Do note that this will change all the timestamps on your commits to now, which is not easily avoidable.  You will need a fairly recent Git version for this to work.

If you want to change all the commits in this branch, back to the very beginning, use `git rebase -x 'git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author' --root` instead.

Comment: I tried to run your commands but I have problems with `error: unknown option 'amend'`, meanwhile the support team replied to me and pointed out that in the local profile was set the wrong email, it was enough to change that, restart the PC and delete and clone the repository, now everything would seem to work, thanks anyway for the help